# Illegal start of Expression java

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I know this is going to be really simple for someone and I can't figure out why the compiler is complaining about this.  I have been looking up for some answers and all I can find is a bracket issue but I don't think that is my problem.  I am new to Java so any help would be awesome.  This is the code that is supposed to be a basic accumulator program.

```
public class BasicAccumulator implements Accumulator {
  {
    private int digit;
    private int value;

  }

  public int basicAccumulator(int digit, int value)
  {
    digit = 0;
    value = 0;
  }

  public void addDigit(int digit);
  {
    digit = digit + value;
  }

  public void plus();
  {
    value = digit + digit;
  }

  public void minus();
  {
    value = digit - digit;
  }

  public void clear();
  {
    value = 0;
  }

  public int displayValue();
  {
    return value;
  }

}
```

Comment: It says there is an error at line 8 and 9, "Illegal start of expression"

Comment: What is the intent of the brackets around the two int fields, digit and value?

Comment: This is not an uncommon type of rookie mistake in languages of this kind.  I +1 your question for asking, though apparently someone disagreed and downvoted.  In this case, any experienced coder will instantly recognize the error, but newbies may spend considerable time overlooking it.  It is far better to ask and learn than not ask and suffer in silence.

Answer (score 5):

```
public void plus();
```

remove semi-colon. It should be:

```
public void plus()
{ ...
}
```

Same for `displayValue()`,minus(), clear(), also. It should be:

Comment: @EricSage: If answer helped you don't forget to accept it by clicking tick mark right beside answer.

Comment: So I removed those and it still spits out the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any IDE? Have you saved your changes? Post the exact message.

Comment: You also need to change `public int basicAccumulator(int digit, int value)` if you are not returning anything to `public void basicAccumulator(int digit, int value)`, but my real guess is you mean for that to be a constructor so it should be `public BasicAccumulator(int digit, int value)`.

Comment: I did save my changes and I am trying to compile from cmd.  It just says illegal start of expression on line 8 and 9 on the p in private.

Comment: @EricSage: Remove the braces surronded private variables.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked.  Why is it that I don't need brackets around private but I do public variables?

Comment: You are confusing variables and methods. Methods need brackets to contain/group their actual functionality they perform when called. Not all languages need the brackets (i.e. python) and use other means such as indentation to perform the same task.

Comment: @EricSage: I hope jschoen answer helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post my comments directly in your code:

```
public class BasicAccumulator implements Accumulator {

    //I'd delete this brackets and leave just the private declarations initialized
    //in zero.
    {
        private int digit;
        private int value;    
    }

    //I'm making this an initializing constructor by using the parameters
    //it defines. If you want both digit and value to be set to 0 (or any other value
    //by default) you can make a no argument constructor and invoke it.
    public BasicAccumulator(int digit, int value)
    {
        this.digit = digit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void addDigit(int digit); //This semicolon is wrong. Delete it.
    {
        digit = digit + value;
    }

    public void plus(); //This semicolon is wrong. Delete it.
    {
        value = digit + digit;
    }

    public void minus(); //This semicolon is wrong. Delete it.
    {
        value = digit - digit;
    }

    public void clear(); //This semicolon is wrong. Delete it.
    {
        value = 0;
    }

    public int displayValue(); //This semicolon is wrong. Delete it.
    {
        return value;
    }

}
```

I don't know if this was an example or anything but there are some issues with the logic too, but I'll leave those to you (the `minus` method in particular, since it will always set the value to 0).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void plus();
public void minus();
public void clear();
public int displayValue();
```

**The above lines in code is the error..**

```
public void plus();
{
    value = digit + digit;
}
```

Let it be like this...

```
public void plus()
{
    value = digit + digit;
}
```

Do this for the remaining methods.....

Answer (score 0):

what are those semicolons doing after signatures of functions addDigit, plus, minus, clear and two below that? Remove them. That will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code has three problems.

1. You have semi-colons after all your methods. The only time you use this is when you have an abstract method (declared `abstract` in an abstract class or in an interface).
2. It looks like you tried to create `digit` and `value` in an initializer block. Remove the brackets around them.
3. Constructors do not return a value, so the return type is never included in its signature. You have `public int basicAccumulator` but it should be just `public BasicAccumulator`. Also, keep an eye on case-sensitivity.

Here is your fixed code:

```
public class BasicAccumulator implements Accumulator {

    private int digit;
    private int value;

    public BasicAccumulator(int digit, int value) {
        digit = 0;
        value = 0;
    }

    public void addDigit(int digit) {
        digit = digit + value;
    }

    public void plus() {
        value = digit + digit;
    }

    public void minus() {
        value = digit - digit;
    }

    public void clear() {
        value = 0;
    }

    public int displayValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```